Conormal sheaf is locally free for regular embeddings
I'm reading Ravi Vakil's The Rising Sea and I'm struggling a bit with the following fact:

21.2.16. Proposition. — 
(a) If the ideal $I \subset B$ is generated by a regular sequence $x_1,\, \dots,\, x_r$, then the map $\gamma: (B/I)^{\oplus r} \rightarrow I/I^2$ given by $$(a_1,\,\dots,\,a_r) \mapsto a_1 x_1 + \cdots +a_r x_r$$ is an isomorphism, hence describing $I/I^2$ as a free module of rank $r$ over $B/I$ with basis $x_1,\,\dots,\, x_r$.(b) The (co)normal sheaf of a codimension $r$ regular embedding is locally free of rank $r$.

There is a proof of this proposition in the notes, and while I mostly understand part (a), the proof for part (b) simply claims that it follows from part (a). The problem for me is that I don't really see how this follows in full generality.
The part that bothers me is that the regular embedding is a pointwise condition, but local freeness is checked on open subsets. On one hand, if we knew that our scheme is locally Noetherian, we would have the fact that the regular embedding is an open condition, which would give us a regular sequence for the ideal on the open set, not just at a point. However, Prof. Vakil specifically wrote that no Noetherian condition is necessary.
On the other hand, if we knew that our conormal sheaf is of finite presentation, we could check local freeness stalk-wise, and part (a) immediately implies that the conormal sheaf has free stalks. But I don't see how to prove that it is of finite presentation.

I'm coming into this cold, but I just googled and looked at 2 versions of the notes. One is Nov. 2017, and it looks like in part (a) he assumes that $A$ (or $B$, if you like) is noetherian, so that makes me think he is implicitly assuming locally noetherian in part (b). The other is Feb. 2024, and he assumes (explicitly) locally noetherian in part (b).

@Dave, it is true, that in previous versions of his notes Prof. Vakil assumed Noetherian hypothesis. But in the newest version he explicitly stated that no Noetherian condition needed
